# My wrapperlist is not showing up

Tags: apex, visualforce, map, wrapper-class, aggregateresult

I trying to create a table to provide metrics on the number of Account and Contact records grouped by state. So each state will have two number of count id.

Below is a code for my class and visual force page

Class

```
public with sharing class SampleController {
   public list<stateWrapper> recordlist { get; set;}
   public class stateWrapper {
        public String stateName;
        public Integer contactCount;
        public Integer accountCount;

        //Default constructor for innerClass
        public stateWrapper(
            String stateName, 
            Integer contactCount, 
            Integer accountCount
        ){
            this.stateName = stateName;
            this.contactCount = contactCount;
            if ( contactCount == null ){
                contactcount = 0;
            }
            this.accountCount = accountCount;
            if ( accountCount == null ){
                accountCount = 0;
            }
            //the above this keyword denotes that we are talking about
            //the variables outside the constructor and not
            //the input parameters by the same name.
        }
    }

    public static Map<String,stateWrapper> calculateMetrics(){
        Map<String,stateWrapper> stateMap = 
            new Map<String,stateWrapper>();
        for ( AggregateResult ar : [    
            Select Count(id) cnt, BillingState state
            from Account 
            where BillingState != null 
            group by BillingState
        ]){
            stateWrapper sw = new stateWrapper(
                (string)ar.get('state'),
                (integer)ar.get('cnt'),
                null
            );
            stateMap.put(sw.stateName,sw);
        }
        for ( AggregateResult ar : [    
            Select Count(id) cnt, MailingState state
            FROM TargetX_SRMb__Application__c
                WHERE TargetX_SRMb__College__c = 'Chicago-Kent College of Law' 
                And TargetX_SRMb__Start_Term_Year__c = '2019'
                And TargetX_SRMb__Start_Term__c = 'Fall'
                And TargetX_SRMb__Level__c = 'Graduate'
                And TargetX_App__Is_Test_Record__c = False
                And TargetX_SRMb__Application_Submit_Date__c != Null 
                And IIT_Sent_For_Faculty_Decision__c = Null
                And TargetX_SRMb__Application_Decision__c = Null
                GROUP BY IIT_Program__r.Name, Department__c, TargetX_SRMb__College__c
        ]){
            stateWrapper sw = new stateWrapper(
                (string)ar.get('state'),
                null,
                null
            );
            if ( stateMap.containsKey(sw.stateName) ){
                sw = stateMap.get(sw.stateName);
            }
            sw.contactCount = (integer)ar.get('cnt');
            stateMap.put(sw.stateName,sw);
        }
        return stateMap;
    }
}
```

This is my visualforce page

```
<apex:page controller="SampleController" >
     <apex:pageBlock >
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!recordlist}" var="a" title="My Badges" columns="4" align="center"  styleClass="table table-striped">
           <apex:facet name="header">Account and Contact State DashBoard </apex:facet> 
            <apex:column > <apex:facet name="header">State</apex:facet>
           {!a['stateName']}</apex:column>
            <apex:column > <apex:facet name="header">Number of Contacts</apex:facet>
           {!a['contactCount']}</apex:column>
            <apex:column > <apex:facet name="header">Number of Accounts</apex:facet>
           {!a['accountCount']}</apex:column>
       </apex:pageBlockTable>
     </apex:pageBlock> 
 </apex:page>
```

Screenshot of my visualforce page showing nothing[image]:

Answer (score 0):

You need to use property variables in the wrapper class, see below :

instead of this

```
public class stateWrapper {
        public String stateName ;
        public Integer contactCount;
        public Integer accountCount;
```

you have to use like this

```
public class stateWrapper {
        public String stateName { get; set;} 
        public Integer contactCount { get; set;}
        public Integer accountCount { get; set;}
```

this should work, check the below example :

```
public with sharing class SampleController {
 public SampleController(){
 recordlist =new list<stateWrapper>();
 stateWrapper  sw = new stateWrapper('Test',10,20);
 recordlist.add(sw);
 }

   public list<stateWrapper> recordlist { get; set;}
   public class stateWrapper {
        public String stateName { get; set;} ;
        public Integer contactCount { get; set;}
        public Integer accountCount { get; set;}

        //Default constructor for innerClass
        public stateWrapper(
            String stateName, 
            Integer contactCount, 
            Integer accountCount
        ){
            this.stateName = stateName;
            this.contactCount = contactCount;
            if ( contactCount == null ){
                contactcount = 0;
            }
            this.accountCount = accountCount;
            if ( accountCount == null ){
                accountCount = 0;
            }
            //the above this keyword denotes that we are talking about
            //the variables outside the constructor and not
            //the input parameters by the same name.
        }
   }}
```

here im diractly passing Wrapper details from the SampleController class constructor

```
stateWrapper  sw = new stateWrapper('Test',10,20);
 recordlist.add(sw);
```

[image]